# How to execute an action without going to another view in grails?

Tags: ajax, grails, controller, action

I have a code that starts the server and stops the server. However when i press the button the  server gets started but it also redirects me to a new view. The code in controller i have is

```
def test= amazonWebService.ec2.startInstances(new StartInstancesRequest([InstanceToStart]))
```

I want to execute test when button is pressed without going to new view. The code I have in my gsp page is

```
 <g:link action="test">
        <input type="button" value="Start Server" class="button" id="startServer1" />
    </g:link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the page refreshing, in your test action, redirect to the same view you came from.  So assuming you got to your current view via index:

```
class SomeController {

   def index() {
     // index.gsp rendered via convention
   }

   def test() {
      // execute your code then
      redirect action: index, params: params
   }
}
```

You're other option is to submit an Ajax request when the link is clicked and not have to refresh the page at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a remote function, see here http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

Following is the alternative answer to the question.

By default Grails view resolver tries to find a view similar to the action name. In your case, Grails is trying to find test.gsp and if it is there in your repository it renders that. You can override this behaviour by using the Grails URL mappings feature. There you will get to specify which view should be rendered for a certain action.

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = { 
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ 
            constraints { 
            // apply constraints here 
            } 
        }

    "/"(view:"/index") 
    "500"(view:'/error') 

    } 
}
```

For further information visit : http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html